# Performing a Select statement with MSSQL (does work with MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have connected to MSSQL, but i am unaware to do a select statement and print it out. I have done this using MySQL, but unable to convert it to MSSQL. Can someone help me to find the equvalent for `mysql_query`,`mysql_real_escape_string`,`mysql_num_rows`,`mysql_fetch_array` or a sample code that helps.

```
// Connecting to MSSQL -  Working
$name = $_POST['myname'];
$x=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($x);    
  while($norows = mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
// PRINT ROW
}
```

Comment: Searching for "php mssql" turns up, unsurprisingly, quite a few options. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

[Use mssql_* functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

Or try PDO: [PDO_SQLSRV driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)

Answer (score 3):

In MSSQL there are the following alternative functions :

```
mysql_query              ---> mssql_query
mysql_num_rows           ---> mssql_num_rows
mysql_fetch_array        ---> mssql_fetch_array
```

Take a look at the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) for more information ...

The only missing function is the escape string(`mysql_real_escape_string`), for that purpose you can define yourself a function like this one :

```
function mssql_escape($str) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str= stripslashes($str);
    }
    return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there anything else for `mysql_real_escape_string` so i could use it in the WHERE clause ?

Comment: Yes, define the function on your own, see the function : mssql_escape that i posted ...